# How can I get Windows 7 to remember program windows size and position?

Tags: windows-7, display, window

I can open Outlook and it fills about half of the screen. I then maximize it to read some mail and then minimize it to do some other work.

When I click on it again in the taskbar, it is back to the original size that it opened at.

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-close and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-maximize but neither seems to work.

This also happens with Explorer windows, AutoCAD, Revit, and other programs that I work with.
Shouldn't a minimize and a maximize bring the window back to the last size and position?

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/240362/save-window-locations-of-applications and http://superuser.com/questions/229134/program-for-scanning-saving-and-restoring-window-position

Answer (score 4):

As user *harrymc*, I checked: Maximize + minimize + click on Windows 7 does return an Explorer window as maximized.

Try with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + close on the window (to save its position and size). This may help!

Comment: This worked for another window that I was having trouble with! Can you explain this? Why does this tip work?

Comment: why? Because it's computer science ... I'm sorry to say that :)

Answer (score 0):

[WindowManager](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm) supposedly does this. There's a forum thread about the problem [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/8801-make-windows-7-remember-window-positions-size.html).

Comment: His problem is not remembering positions between invocations of the programs, but that de-minimizing a maximized window doesn't restore it as maximized.

Comment: I believe I may have it solved. It seems to behave properly as long as you don't snap it to the edge of the screen to maximize it. I can drag the edge of the window to near the edge of the screen to a point where it is about to snap and then minimize the window. When I click on it in the taskbar again, it opens up to the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it: Maximize + minimize + click on Windows 7 does return an Explorer window as maximized. What you are describing is not a normal behavior.

- Try it after booting in Safe mode.
- If this fixes the problem, then some installed software is interfering.
- If it doesn't, try ["sfc /scannow"](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) and some virus scans.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WindowPadX](https://github.com/hoppfrosch/WindowPadX). It has some nice features including windows positions and area definition.

Answer (score -1):

Hello: Ctrl + the upper right X to close the window makes the >Os remember the size; valid for Windows XP and 7.

Comment: The OP wants the window size to be recalled after minimizing, not closing.

Comment: Tog you are right; in 14 years using MS Microsoft applications I don´t recall that minimizing will alter the size of the window. Not many direct references to this issue in Goggle. This is somehow related so might help http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f1650402-0770-4c46-9f8d-5299e40f06b2/how-do-i-make-windows-7-remember-different-window-positions-and-size?forum=w7itproui

Answer (score -1):

There was a way to do that back in Windows 3.1 by holding the SHIFT key, and then in the program file menu select "Exit".  I just tried it in Windows 7 Professional and it seems to still work.

Comment: This was suggested 3 years ago.