# Is there a program for scanning, saving and restoring window position?

Tags: windows, display

Is there some program for scanning, saving and restoring last window position?

For example at this moment I have opened five windows:

- The first is Google Chrome, which is not opened at full screen but at half of the display.
- The second is Notepad, which is on the right side.
- The third is `cmd` which is under Notepad.

So I want to use this combination of "layout" when primarily using Google Chrome (surfing the internet), but if working primarily in another program, let's say Word (writting text), I want to use other programs and at different positions (cause is effectively).

So the point is to easy switching from one "layout" to another. (Like in many program that support more modes, for example visual studio -> debug layout, -> coding layout, etc ...)

Comment: WTF closed as not constructive?? Anyway some pointers: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/ ; http://www.displayfusion.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WindowManager](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm)

This is not a freeware but you can try it out. 
I am not sure if it is capable of opening/remembering multiple instances of the same application.

Comment: thnx sahil, that is something like that ...:)

Comment: WindowManager doesn't solve my problem, which is along similar lines. It doesn't recognize stuff automatically (pain to configure!) and doesn't support multiple profiles. I need something that will run through all windows and save their positions at a touch of a button, restoring when another button is pressed. Bah! I guess I'll need to code it myself. Maybe AHK will help.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the Windows command prompt all ways opens to its default size, I don't know that there is any way around this.  For your other programs your windows should open where they were when they were last closed.  An exception to this rule is using the WIN key plus arrow keys, in which case the size of the window is not remembered, but as long as you manually adjust your window sizes then they should open where they were last closed.

Comment: yes it is true but point of this is to customize one time most effectivly "layout" (position of windows) and use it every time when is necessary for some job, .... window is remember position but if you want to open two time notepad, it will start one above the other, what we want is to start both on some specific various location...