# Is there a good tool for automatically opening, sizing, and placing application windows?

Tags: windows, browser, application-launch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save window locations of applications](https://superuser.com/questions/240362/save-window-locations-of-applications)

A recurrent task at my workplace is opening applications to display monitoring tools, on a multi-monitor display that is repeated by projectors. Mostly, these are Web browser windows. The arrangement of windows is consistent, and it's exactly the sort of nuisance task that calls for automation. Can anyone recommend a good Windows tool for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are dominantly web browser windows, you could create a simple startup Web page (HTML file) or script that will automate the browser window opening process for you, using Javascript to pop open new windows, position them, and resize them according to your spec.

Otherwise, excellent graphics drivers provided by AMD/ATI and NVIDIA provide multiple desktop / application / window management that will save window positions. You will need supporting hardware, of course. There is also desktop window management software available from third-party vendors (search for multiple desktop / window management etc.).

Comment: Thanks. nView is available, though the documentation is a bit sparse. We'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

[Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) can do this through customized application shortcuts; it lets you define position and size, and supports multiple displays.  As long as they're always going to be in exactly the same place this is probably your best bet.