# Locking applications z-order on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lock

Is there a way to lock the ordering of multiple windows even if one is focused?

I have six windows in which I only need to interact with the right edge and would like the layering to be preserved during interaction.

Comment: "interact with the right edge" what do you mean by interaction? With the keyboard or with the mouse?

Comment: @DavidPostill The elements I interact with are aligned to the right side of the window as such I don't need to view the entire window at once. Also interact with mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Ah. If it was just scrolling with the mouse I had an answer :(

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you ask is impossible without programming these windows
to re-position themselves upon a change in the Z-order, or to create a watchdog program that does it for them.

Here are some tools that remember windows arrangement and could perhaps reset
the Z-order of your windows if it changes (listed in no particular order):

- [TaskLayout](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/tasklayout.html)
- [WinSize2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/)
- [WindowsLayoutSnapshot](https://github.com/adamsmith/WindowsLayoutSnapshot)
- [WindowManager](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm) ($10)

Or you could role your own tool using a [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)
script.
Here are some examples to get you started:

- [Saving and restoring windows layout?](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/65340-saving-and-restoring-windows-layout/)
- [Is it possible to retain multi monitor settings when one monitor is unplugged](https://superuser.com/a/825764/8672)
- [GUI control z-order](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/86330-gui-control-z-order/)
- [How to get the id of the next or previous window in Z order](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32171-how-to-get-the-id-of-the-next-or-previous-window-in-z-order/)

Comment: I'll add another similar program to the list: [Persistent Windows](https://github.com/kangyu-california/PersistentWindows)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [WindowsLayoutSnapshot](https://github.com/adamsmith/WindowsLayoutSnapshot) from the list [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) has provided.

It's an open-source utility that allows you to save a snapshot of your window configurations that you can return to at a later date. You might be able to get further help recoding this application to fit your needs on StackOverflow or here on SuperUser.

Edit: because this is open source, you are able to edit it. It's unlicensed and available in the public domain. If you make a timer you can probably use this to do what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [DeskPins](https://efotinis.neocities.org/deskpins/index.html). It's just a "always in front" feature, but it works and is a really simple program.