# Program window, or Game window size

Tags: windows-8

So I just bought an Alienware 13 laptop. It has been great until I ran into this problem. It's not TOOO big of a deal but just real annoying. When I downloaded minecraft, I noticed that the launcher AND game itself was a much smaller size than what it needed to be.

[image]

To help understand better the size of the screen/window difference, here is my description.

I have a 13" wide computer screen (use a tape measure if you have to) with about 3/4" of trim on both sides. So the screen itself is about 11 1/2" wide. When I open up Minecraft, it does it's launcher text stuff, (in super small window size) and then goes to the PLAY button section (which gets slightly bigger. From the inside trim edge on my screen on the right, to the right side of the window (using a tape) is about 3 1/2 inches and about the same on the other side. I just want you to know HOW small it is.

Anyway, i can re-size the window by pulling the corners to the desired width/height. The window will then stay this way until I click the PLAY button and the game launches, then I have to re-size the window all over again, but it will stay this way until I close out and re-open it. I have looked all over the internet for a solution and found similar problems, but were all fixed by something or another that didn't work for me. This also happens with SF2 (soldier Front 2). In the lobby, it is also super small, and only until I go to fullscreen when in a match, will it be...well, fullscreen.

What iv'e tried:

1. I changed the screen resolution and it did make my programs bigger, but cut some of my desktop off and made my icons really big.
2. I opened up the program that was having problems, re-sized it to the desired size. Then held shift and closed out (Holding shift while clicking the X button. I also did this holding Control and alt and windows key. and the FN key. And when I reopened the program, it would go back to miniature size.

I read somewhere that it might be my graphics settings or something like that, but the options in the settings they were talking about, weren't in mine.

I did however get minecraft GAME window to stay how I wanted it to by opening up the options.txt in the .minecraft folder and overwriting the window size that way. But this didn't change the launcher, only the initial game window. I have an NVIDIA graphics card if that helps. I also downloaded TERA Online and have the same problem with that aswell. It seems to mostly be with game application windows.

I hope someone has a solution, this is aggravating.
:P

Comment: Post the image on a file sharing site such as http://imgur.com then post just a link here, a higher reputation user can edit it in for you.

Comment: Ok, so I uploaded the image to imgur.com and heres the link:       http://imgur.com/gSzMkK5

Comment: Is this any help? http://superuser.com/questions/174757/how-can-i-get-windows-7-to-remember-program-windows-size-and-position

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to change the default size of launcher window. It appears tiny to you due to your high DPI monitor combined with screen scaling being enabled.